# How to handle empty objects with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift2, nscalendar

I have an app that keeps track of monthly expenses. I have an **Expense** entity with a **month** attribute that keeps track of current month expense is created on. I would then display the expenses for each month in a table view  as shown here. The user can only switch left and right only if there are expenses within the next or the last month

```
@IBAction func backMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Back Button Pressed")
    currentMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: currentMonth, options: [])!
    if checkMonth(currentMonth) {
        updateFetch()
        setMonth()
    } else {
        currentMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: currentMonth, options: [])!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()

}

@IBAction func nextMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Next Button Pressed")

    currentMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: 1, toDate: currentMonth, options: [])!
    if checkMonth(currentMonth) {
        updateFetch()
        setMonth()
    } else {
        currentMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: -1, toDate: currentMonth, options: [])!
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func checkMonth(month : NSDate) -> Bool {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext //scratch pad

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month == %@", month.MonthYearDateFormatter())
    let count = context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
    if count > 0 {
        print("There are expenses for this month \(month.MonthYearDateFormatter()). Show expenses")
        return true

    } else {
        print("There are no expenses for this month \(month.MonthYearDateFormatter()). Do Nothing")
        return false
    }
}
```

My problem is this, in the unlikely scenario that the user created an expense back in June and didn't create an expense in August. How can I let the user still see his/her expense back in August without skipping it. Any ideas?

Comment: Fetch all of your expenses at once and store them in an array, sorted by month.  Then just navigate through the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some optimisation before elaboration:

```
@IBAction func backMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.processMonth(step: -1)
}

@IBAction func nextMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.processMonth(step: 1)
}

// a method uses almost the same code for both cases, so it was merged
func processMonth(step: Int) {
    let direction = (step < 1 ? "Back" : "Next")
    print("\(direction) Button Pressed")

    currentMonth = NSCalendar.currentCalendar().dateByAddingUnit(.Month, value: step, toDate: currentMonth, options: [])!

    //if checkMonth(currentMonth) {
    // I wouldn't test this because it locks you out from seeing empty month.
        updateFetch()
        setMonth()
    //}

    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

An answer to what you've exactly asked:

If your data source for your UITableView is set properly, you should be able to go through empty months though

```
// changed return type from `Bool` to `void` as I suggested in the method not to test empty month, as it could be useless

func checkMonth(month : NSDate) {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext //scratch pad

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")
    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month == %@", month.MonthYearDateFormatter())
    let count = context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)
    if count > 0 {
        print("There are expenses for this month \(month.MonthYearDateFormatter()). Show expenses")

    } else {
        print("There are no expenses for this month \(month.MonthYearDateFormatter()). Do Nothing")
        // here you can make some additional actions, like seeting the empty table with "no expenses this month"
    }
}
```

Anyway, as **@Paulw11** noted, if your data source is not size-exhausting, you could rather fetch the data from your data-model at viewDidLoad/viewDidAppear for example and then to render each month according to the `currentMonth` variable (regarding what month a user currently see).

So as a result, you would call `setMonth()` method only in the load of your controller and each time a user changes a current month view.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of @Paulw11 and @pedrouan, I was able to do what I wanted.

Fetch all expenses

```
    func fetchExpenses() {
    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext //scratch pad
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")

    //Always Sort Budget by the date it's created
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]

    do {
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(fetchRequest)
        self.expenses = results as! [Expense]
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.debugDescription)
    }
}
```

Set constraints to first and last month to determine how far a user can navigate through months in viewDidLoad

```
    //If array is not empty, set first and last month
    if expenses.count > 0 {
        guard let first = expenses.first?.month else {
            return
        }
        firstMonth = first

        guard let last = expenses.last?.month else {
            return
        }
        lastMonth = last

    }else {
        //Set current month to be first and last
        firstMonth = currentMonth.MonthYearDateFormatter()
        lastMonth = currentMonth.MonthYearDateFormatter()
    }
```

Limit user from going past first and last month

```
    @IBAction func backMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("Back Button Pressed")
    if currentMonth.MonthYearDateFormatter() != firstMonth {
        self.processMonth(step: -1)
    }
}

@IBAction func nextMonthButtonPressed(sender: AnyObject) {

    print("Next Button Pressed")
    if currentMonth.MonthYearDateFormatter() !=  lastMonth {
        self.processMonth(step: 1)
    }
}
```

Return all the expenses in current month and if there's none clear fetch and return empty table.

```
  func updateFetch() {
    setFetchResults()

    do {
        try self.fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
    } catch {
        let error = error as NSError
        print("\(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}


func setFetchResults() {

    let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = app.managedObjectContext //scratch pad

    //Fetch Request
    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Expense")

    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: "created", ascending: false)

    fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "month == %@", currentMonth.MonthYearDateFormatter())
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    let count = context.countForFetchRequest(fetchRequest, error: nil)


    let controller = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: ad.managedObjectContext , sectionNameKeyPath: section, cacheName: nil)

    //If there is none, empty fetch request
    if count == 0 {
        print("There are no expenses for this month. Show nothing")
        controller.fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(value: false)
    } else {
        print("There are expenses for this month. Show expenses")
    }

    fetchedResultsController = controller
    controller.delegate = self
}
```

With pedroruan's processMonth(), I was able to navigate through empty tableViews so that user can see that August is empty while still being able to go to June's month. Thanks guys.